# Ruby and graph DB w/o Jruby

Tags: ruby, graph-databases

I'm hoping to introduce a graph DB into my project w/o having to move to jRuby. As I see it, given this restriction I've got two options:

1. Use a graph DB that provides a RESTful interface. I don't know what impact this will have on performance. I'm planning for a crapload of data.
2. Find a graph DB that has a ruby interface not requiring jRuby. In my search thus far I've not found anything but most of the posts and blog entries I've found have been fairly dated. I'd prefer the DB and interface to be somewhat mature and reliable, of course.

Does anyone know of anything that would meet #2 above?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid JRuby? It's an excellent platform.

Comment: I am working in an existing project that uses 1.9.3--recently migrated from 1.9.2. Changing to a completely different platform isn't in the schedule at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about performance, I'd recommend trying JRuby and neo4j.rb 
because it interacts directly with the embedded, high performance neo4j-Java-API. Ultimately I think that would be the highest-performance solution.

If you're not willing to entertain JRuby at all, there are options. Neo4j has a REST API and [neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography) is a thin wrapper for it.

Or you use the Neo4j Server - [(J)Ruby extension](https://github.com/neo4j/script-extension). This is a JRuby Rack application that exposes a REST API. It contains the Neo4J server, so it can be installed and used as a JRuby app, and your stack is Ruby all the way down, even if it is mostly MRI Ruby and the JRuby part is isolated to persistence.

Comment: So neography is an option then?